# gSoap with openSSL or wininet_plugin plugin on windows

Tags: c++, openssl, exchangewebservices, gsoap, wininet

I'm using gSoap on windows, I need Authentication on exchange server for fetching their email data. Since for example on microsoft exchange server (office365) the

loginID: abcd@abcd.onmicrosoft.com

password: PASSword

If I understand correctly they use SSL so either I need wininet_plugin plugin or openSSL for this.

The chapter 19.22 of gSoap documentation (SSL on Windows) says:

"For systems based on Microsoft windows, the WinInet module can be used instead"

My main aim to implement a Exchange web services with CUSTOM exchange server to fetch and send email data, So which method of SSL is better and easy for this purpose. Also is this Auth depend on which platform this gSoap's code should run on client side.

Thank you,

Comment: This is my endpoint url: https://outlook.office365.com/ews/exchange.asmx